# how to click forcefully on a security checkout button in iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to click a button on iframe window security checkout using JavaScript .

In normal window (except iframe) we use,

```
document.getElementById("ButtonId").click()
```

But In iframe window this case is not working fine. As I think this is a security check out which is restricting me to achieve this task.

I have done the following Steps:

```
document.getElementById("Buttonid").click()
window.frames["frameId"].document.getElementById("Buttonid").click()
```

I am getting this error:

> `window.frames['frameId'].document` is undefined

Comment: Short answer: You can't if this iframe is on different domain.

Comment: ... and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) explains why.

Comment: Is the URL in the iframe on the same domain as the main page?

Comment: yes URL in iframe is in different domain, then how can we do it?

Comment: @DeepikaMohadikar antyrat has answered the question already. However, if you can control the page in iframe, you can use methods represented at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

Comment: yeah!!! This issue is resolved .. while invoking browser just add this flag.. chromium-browser --disable-web-security.. Thanks to all..